# Multiple NICS with docker swarm

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

Hi just a general question - can one create an overlay network on docker swarm bound to a secondary ethernet card (all nodes have two ethernet cards and can communicate on the secondary private lan as well, i.e. if I ping another host using its secondary IP it uses the private lan) with a different address range than the address range used with --advertise-addr when they joined the swarm? The idea is to have certain containers communicating with each other over the new overlay network because it is faster.

OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04
Docker app version: Docker engine Community edition 19.03.1

Any info would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a better way of doing this by splitting the control and data planes by passing data-path-addr param to the swarm init command. My containers are now communicating via the faster link, and the control traffic is routed via the primary NICs.